# Can I get all my friends checked into a particular page/place given that I know the page_id?

Tags: facebook, graph, facebook-fql, checkin

```
SELECT author_uid FROM checkin  WHERE page_id IN ('314124218488')
```

When I do that I get an empty [].

but if I do

```
SELECT checkin_id, author_uid, page_id FROM checkin 
WHERE page_id IN ('314124218488') AND author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

I do get one of my friend however this is really really slow!! since if i have about 500 or more checkins from my friends, it is going to check all my friends against the check-in object!

why cant i get people/friends checked into the page by just doing:

```
SELECT author_uid FROM checkin  WHERE page_id IN ('314124218488')
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I managed to fix it.

1. When using the checkin query, make sure all the permissions are correct, try using the api explorer. http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET, i found that checking the permission:friends_notes i could get all the info i needed. Make sure you also check relevant permissions like: friends_location etc when getting an access token(you get a temporary one using the explorer)
2. Try the API query `<PAGEID>/checkins?fields=from,message` in the explorer

No user ID is needed and you get all the friends that checked in to the page with the pageid `<PAGEID>`.